# Scheme/Racket: How to do repeating in defining syntax

Tags: parsing, syntax, scheme, racket, definition

I can define the infix '+' as below in Racket:

```
(require syntax/parse/define (only-in racket (#%app racket:#%app)))
(define-syntax-parser #%app
  [(_ Value1 {~datum +} Value2)
  #'(+ Value1 Value2)]

  [(_ Xs ...) 
  #'(racket:#%app Xs ...)]
)
(displayln (1 + 2))
```

I want to add multiple infix '+' using `~between` but it doesn't work:

```
(require syntax/parse/define (only-in racket (#%app racket:#%app)))
(define-syntax-parser #%app
  [(_ {~between {Value1 {~datum +}} 1 100} Value2)
  #'(+ Value1 Value2)]

  [(_ Xs ...) 
  #'(racket:#%app Xs ...)]
)
(displayln (1 + 2))
```

The syntax in Racket is here: https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html with `~between` but no `~repeat`.

**How to use ~between property to repeat items in syntax?**

I have a work-around but it doesn't look pure multiple infix `+`, need to wrap every left entry in brackets:

```
(require syntax/parse/define (only-in racket (#%app racket:#%app)))
(define-syntax-parser #%app
  [(_ {Value1 {~datum +}} ... Value2)
  #'(+ Value1 ... Value2)]

  [(_ Xs ...) 
  #'(racket:#%app Xs ...)]
)
(displayln ({1 +} {2 +} 3))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a combination of [`~seq`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse..rkt%29._~7eseq%29%29) and [`...+`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse..rkt%29._......%2B%29%29).

```
(define-syntax-parser #%app
  [(_ {~seq Value1 {~datum +}} ...+ Value2)
   #'(+ Value1 ... Value2)]
  [(_ Xs ...) 
   #'(racket:#%app Xs ...)])
```

The [`~seq`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse..rkt%29._~7eseq%29%29) matches a sequence of things *without* requiring them to be grouped by brackets as your workaround did.

The [`...+`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse..rkt%29._......%2B%29%29) is a repetition pattern to match one-or-more things, as opposed to zero-or-more. This makes sure that `(f)` isn't accidentally interpreted as `(+ f)`.

One more note, when you're defining `#%app` directly, as opposed to defining under a different name and then renaming the export, you need to be extra careful about implicit recursive uses. For instance `(+ + x)` is an infinite loop. To fix that you could use `racket:#%app` in both outputs, like `#'(racket:#%app + Value1 ... Value2)`.

```
(define-syntax-parser #%app
  [(_ {~seq Value1 {~datum +}} ...+ Value2)
   #'(racket:#%app + Value1 ... Value2)]
  [(_ Xs ...) 
   #'(racket:#%app Xs ...)])
```